# jquery highlight the link when clicked

Tags: jquery, highlight

How do I use jquery to highlight the link when I click on it?

For example, when I click on the link class1_1, I want to make this link red (or another color).

The javascript code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $("#menu li").each(function(){
     $(this).click(function(event){
       var ul=$(this).children("ul")
       var span = $(this).children("span")
       if(ul.html()!=null)
       {
          if(ul.css("display")=="none")
          {
            ul.css("display","block");
            span.addClass("up")
          }else
          {
            ul.css("display","none")
            span.removeClass("up")
          }
           event.stopPropagation();
       }else
       {
         event.stopPropagation();
       }
     });
  });
  return false;
 });
</script>
```

The html code here:

```
<ul id="menu">

<li class="title"><span>class1 </span>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">class1_1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">class1_2</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
<li class="title"><span>class2</span>
   <ul>
  <li><span>class2_1</span>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">class2_1_1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">class2_1_1</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

maybe I can't explanation my question clearly,I mean is the last onclick link make it

color to red and another links set to there default color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $("#menu li").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(event) {

            $("#menu li").removeClass("high");
            $(this).addClass("high");

            var ul = $(this).children("ul")
            var span = $(this).children("span")
            if (ul.html() != null) {
                if (ul.css("display") == "none") {
                    ul.css("display", "block");
                    span.addClass("up")
                } else {
                    ul.css("display", "none") span.removeClass("up")
                }
                event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
</script>


<style>
.high{color:red}
</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

It's possible using CSS, no jQuery required:

Highlight:

```
a:active {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Change link color:

```
a:active {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Edit: Responding to your comment... If your links are not directing the browser to another page, you can use [Mike Robinson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813046/jquery-highlight-the-link-when-clicked/813083#813083) to accomplish the same effect without leaving the page and without changing the color back to default onblur.

Comment: if use a:active,onblur the color will disappear

Answer (score 5):

Think this should do it, although I don't have jquery on hand right now. Assumes 'up' is a class that makes your link red:

```
$("ul#menu a").click(function(){
 $(this).addClass('up');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**This should work:**

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.class1').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active1');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
a.class1 { color: red; }
a.active1 { color: blue; }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="class1">some text</a>
```

Its better to use toggleClass (2 in 1) instead of addClass/removeClass.

Comment: But if have more than two links of it ,for example

<a href="#" class="class1">some text</a>

<a href="#" class="class1">some text too</a>

<a href="#" class="class1">some text too1</a>
...
if onclick the "some text too" how can I reset "some text" color to it default color? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color jquery.color plugin. It will allow you to animate color on all sorts of html elements.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hi')) {
        // If this link is not already highlighted, highlight it and make
        // sure other links of class .link are not highlighted.
        $('.hi').removeClass('hi');
        $(this).addClass('hi');
    }
});
```

css:

```
a.hi { color: red; }
```

html:

```
<a href="#" class="link">my text</a>
<a href="#" class="link">that text</a>
<a href="#" class="link">this text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the CSS pseudo-class **active**. It adds special style to an activated element.

For example you can do this:

```
a: active { color: red; }
```

Be careful, a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order to be effective!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var base = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
var links="";
$('a').click(function(){
    links = $(this).attr('href');
    localStorage.setItem(base, links);
});
```

$('a[href="'+localStorage.getItem(base)+'"]').focus();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).