# Permanently Highlight an javascript item upon clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, highlight, nav

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery highlight the link when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813046/jquery-highlight-the-link-when-clicked)

I have this nav:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-filter=".cat1">Category 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-filter=".cat2">Category 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-filter=".cat3">Category 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this jquery code managing a plugin:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('#content_iso');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
        }
    });
    $('#nav a').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
        }
    });

  return false;
});
```

});

there are some Css for animation...but not important. The thing is: I want to make the nav link to be highlighted when I click on it, but then when i click on the other link I want this to be highlighted and the other one not. I tried adding

```
$(this).css('border', 'solid black');
```

to the click function, but it would only highlight and not undo it when clicking the next link. Help please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
   $('#nav a').css('border',''); // <== add this line : remove border on other links
   $(this).css('border', 'solid black');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wu9fk/)

Answer (score 3):

Use css class instead:

```
.active{border:1px solid black}

$('#nav a').click(function(){
    $('a.active','#nav').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Agreed, CSS is the best practice for this UI effect.  JavaScript can be used to accomplish the same but it takes considerably more code and is less intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could style your elements via a CSS-class, remove this class from all navigation links on click and add it to the clicked one.

```
$('#nav a').click(function() {
   $('#nav a').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');

.selected {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```